# How to create different column size in 2d array

Tags: java

I have two lists of elements and numbers but how can I put them into arrays if I don't know the exact array size? new int[elements.size()][I'm not sure about this size].

For example:

List of elements = [2,5]
List of numbers = [99,100], [1,9,8,10,70]

```
public static int[][] arrays(List<Integer> numbers, List<Integer> elements){
        int count = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int[][] list = new int[elements.size()][];

        for (Integer e : elements) {       
            for (int i = count; i < count+e; i++) { 
                list[x][y] = numbers.get(i);
                y++;
            }
            x++;
            y = 0;
            count += e;
        } 

        return list;  
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about what your expected output is???

For example are you expecting to return a 2 dimensional matrix of with dimensions of [2][5]?
For the first list of numbers, what would you expect to see in the 3rd, 4th and 5th postions (i.e. after the 100)?

A more java-y way would be to return an array of lists or even better a list of lists where each entry corresponds to one of the List of Numbers elements?

Anyway some informaiton on the problem you are trying to solve might yield a "better" method than the very specific question that you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The correct input for your method would be a list of lists, with each list in the parent list potentially having a different length:

```
public static int[][] arrays(List<List<Integer>> numbers) {
    int[][] array = new int[numbers.size()][];

    for (int i=0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
        array[i] = new int[numbers.get(i).size()];
        for (int j=0; j < numbers.get(i).size(); ++j) {
            array[i][j] = numbers.get(i).get(j);
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: so it is not possible at all to create the arrays using the two lists I have provided?

Comment: I don't even understand your current method.  You are passing in a flat list of numbers, so how do we even know conceptually where one sublist begins and ends?  A list of lists seems like the more likely scenario you would actually be facing.